# Sudden ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I'm generally confused for the first time in awhile. I wrote this code last night in a few minutes and it worked fine. Now suddenly after expanding my list it throws an ArrayIndexOutOfbounds: 63

```
private final String[] itemName = new String['?'];
private final String[] itemID = new String['?'];
private void loadList() throws IOException {
    final URL itemListURL = new URL("testlist.txt");
    final BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(itemListURL.openStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {


        final String[] itemListArray = line.split(",");

        final int i = Integer.parseInt(itemListArray[0]);

        this.itemID[i] = itemListArray[0];
        this.itemName[i] = itemListArray[1];

    }
    buffer.close();
}
```

Could anyone point out what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where did you see the syntax `new String['?']`?

Comment: to add to the above, ['?'] is specifying the size of that array, not some default value which I think you are assuming ;)

Comment: @BilltheLizard Just suppose it was one of those terrible habits I picked up some time ago. I never any problems with it as when its used in other applications they never exceed 63

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private final String[] itemName = new String['?'];
private final String[] itemID = new String['?'];
```

Here you are creating arrays of size 63, which is the ASCII code point for a question mark (`'?'`).

What you are looking for are Lists: they grow if needed.

```
private final List<String> itemName = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I think that in your case, you even don't need the itemID's, because the itemID is equal to the index of the element in the list.

Comment: Thank you, I knew I was over looking something obvious. In this case I use itemID's because some Id's differ from their index.

Comment: Well, the code you showed is not taking that into account. You have: `itemID[i] = i`.